# htaccess RewriteRule and Redirect get not what i expecting

Tags: .htaccess

For example visititors type or open some url, like `www.domain.com/some-url`

I have one php file, that provides conent for all urls. For example, file name is `show_content.php`

In `show_content.php`i get url, using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, then get necessary data from mysql.

To do all above in `.htaccess` i use `RewriteRule ^([\w=/-]+)$ show_content.php?$1 [QSA]`

So far all is ok. But problem is when i want to redirect from non existent url to another url.

I use `Redirect 301 /non-existent-url /another-url`.
Want to see url like `www.domain.com/another-url`, but i see `www.domain.com/another-url?non-existent-url`.

Understand that it is because of `?` in `show_content.php?$1`, but if i remove `?`, then get 404 Not Found.

How to change RewriteRule, to redirect correctly?

Comment: The issue is that you _always_ apply your rewrite rule. You should add a condition there that prevents its application when you do not want it to get applied.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but could you explain more? RewriteRule applies only when visitor types incorrect url. What condition to add, please?

Comment: Why should that be the case? Your rule gets applied without condition, so for _all_ requests as far as I can say.